# How to check if a pandas Series contains Timestamps?

Tags: python, pandas

Following seems to work at least in some cases:

```
series.dtype == np.dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

but it doesn't look pretty and I'm not sure if it works always (with all(?) kinds of Timestamps).

Is there a nicer way for testing whether a column contains Timestamps?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

try this it should work:

```
pd.core.dtypes.common.is_datetime_or_timedelta_dtype(series)
```

if you go through `pd.core.dtypes.common.is_` you will find many options for checking timestamps. If you want to combine them then you can use logical operators like:

```
pd.core.dtypes.common.is_datetime64_ns_dtype(ser)|pd.core.dtypes.common.is_timedelta64_ns_dtype(ser)
```

Comment: this does not work for me, interesting:
data = pd.Series(['2023-07-12 20:04:46', '2023-07-12 20:04:46', '2023-07-12 20:04:46'])
print(pd.core.dtypes.common.is_datetime64_ns_dtype(data)|pd.core.dtypes.common.is_timedelta64_ns_dtype(data))

Comment: Because you have strings, not time or date like types. You have to convert them to timestamps: pd.Series([pd.Timestamp('2023-07-12 20:04:46'), pd.Timestamp('2023-07-12 20:04:46'), pd.Timestamp('2023-07-12 20:04:46')])

Comment: Tried this after converting a list of strings to datetime and got the following error `module 'pandas.core.dtypes.common' has no attribute 'is_datetime_or_timedelta_dtype'` - using `Pandas 2.1.1`

Answer (score 2):

The approach in @shivsn's answer is simpler and most likely better.  This is a harder way that nonetheless may be informative.

See [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.interface.html#arrays-interface) for more details on dtypes.  But in a nutshell, the second character of the dtype string should be 'M' for a Datetime and 'm' for a Timedelta.  Hence, you could test `dtype.str[1] == 'M'` to detect a Datetime only or `dtype.str[1].lower() == 'm'` to detect either a Datetime or Timedelta.

```
>>> dr = pd.date_range('1-1-2017',periods=4,freq='d')
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({ 'i':range(3), 'x':[1.1,2.2,3.3], 
                        'ts':dr[:3], 'td':dr[1:]-dr[:3] })

   i     td         ts    x
0  0 1 days 2017-01-01  1.1
1  1 1 days 2017-01-02  2.2
2  2 1 days 2017-01-03  3.3

>>> for v in df.columns:  
        print( '\ncolumn ' + v + ': ')
        print( 'dtype.str: ', df[v].dtype.str )
        print( 'dtype:     ', df[v].dtype )
        print( 'timestamp? ', df[v].dtype.str[1] == 'M' )

column i: 
dtype.str:  <i8
dtype:      int64
timestamp?  False

column td: 
dtype.str:  <m8[ns]
dtype:      timedelta64[ns]
timestamp?  False

column ts: 
dtype.str:  <M8[ns]
dtype:      datetime64[ns]
timestamp?  True

column x: 
dtype.str:  <f8
dtype:      float64
timestamp?  False
```