# Checking if a python variable is a date?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

One thing that I'm finding hard with the pandas/numpy combo is dealing with dates. My `dataframe` time series indices are often `DateTimeIndex`es containing Timestamps but sometimes seem to be something else (e.g. `datetime.Date` or `numpy.datetime64`).

Is there a generic way to check if a particular object is a date, i.e. any of the known date variable types? Or is that a function I should look to create myself?

Thanks!

Comment: Doesnt seem to be. Why not just create your own function that checks for any those types?

Comment: Some other ways can be found here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44988301/how-to-check-if-a-pandas-series-contains-timestamps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use this function to convert a series to a consistent `datetime` object in `pandas` / `numpy`. It works with both scalars and series.

```
import pandas as pd
x = '2018-12-11'
pd.to_datetime(x)  # Timestamp('2018-12-11 00:00:00')
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. As a general practice do you try to keep all time formats as Timestamps, to keep things simple?

Comment: if i'm working with `pandas`, yes. it's guaranteed to understand it because you are using `pandas` to cast it. it also has a host of convenience features: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html

Answer (score 2):

```
if isinstance(yourVariable,datetime.datetime):
   print("it's a date")
```

Comment: Thanks! - that works for timestamps but not for datetime.date so it's not perfect.

Comment: you can include multiple types, e.g. `isinstance(var, (datetime.datetime, np.datetime64, datetime.date))

Answer (score 1):

I would try converting the string representation of what I suspect to be a datetime into a *datetime object*, using the *parse* function from *dateutil.parser*.

https://chrisalbon.com/python/basics/strings_to_datetime/